# Send email through elastic when error comes in log

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-watcher

I need to send email automatically whenever any error comes in my Elastic search.
Is there anyway to do it.
I dont want to use Elastic Cloud for it.

I can use Watcher in Kibana, but my question is whether the "Watcher" is available in local also along with cloud?
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watcher is available in on-premises installations if you have at least a Gold License, it is not available with the free basic license.

The same thing for the Kibana e-mail action, it needs a Gold License.

You can check what is available at the [subscription](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions) page.

If you do not have a Gold License for your on-premises cluster, you will need an external tool to query elasticsearch and send e-mails, you can build one using one of the official clients libraries (python, node.js, java etc) or you can try other tools like [elastalert](https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert).

Comment: thanks for answering. I setup elasticalert and emails are getting triggered. But i need to send the email whenever the error occurs, so for that I am unable to understand how to add filter in example_frequency.yaml. 
I have posted one more question for the same :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64385509/elastalert-filter-for-apache-errors
Can you please look. It'll be really helpful.
Thanks